# what's the difference between global average and local average in zero centering processing?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-processing

It's necessary to do zero centering processing in image preprocessing phase.But i dont know why some paper substract the global average(the average among the whole training set) while others just substract the local average(the average among the mini-batch). Could you please give me an explanation about it?

**PS**: In zero centering, do we substract the average in each channel?